# Symfony2: My route matches in console, not in browser. Probably due to apache 2.4/php-fpm fcgi config

Tags: php, symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I am totally new to symfony, doing my first exploratory project.

I want to build a REST API, and I installed FOSRestBundle.

In my console, the output of `php app/console router:debug get_usuarios:`

```
[router] Route "get_usuarios"
Name         get_usuarios
Path         /usuarios.{_format}
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       GET
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: MciAPIBundle:Usuarios:getUsuarios
             _format: NULL
Requirements _format: json|xml|html
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/usuarios(?:\.(?P<_format>json|xml|html))?$#s
```

and: `php app/console router:match /usuarios`

```
Route "get_usuarios" matches
[router] Route "get_usuarios"
Name         get_usuarios
Path         /usuarios.{_format}
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       GET
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: MciAPIBundle:Usuarios:getUsuarios
             _format: NULL
Requirements _format: json|xml|html
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/usuarios(?:\.(?P<_format>json|xml|html))?$#s
```

but when I go to my browser and go `http://localhost:7080/usuarios`
I get:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
```

I don't get it: if it says (in the console) that it matches, why doesn't it match in the browser?

app/config/routing.yml

```
get_usuarios:
    type: rest
    resource: Mci\APIBundle\Controller\UsuariosController
```

EDIT: To me it seems that the Controller is not even loaded ever. If I put garbage in that controller nothing happens, still the same 404 error

**EDIT 2:**I believe it has to do with my webserver 2.4 and php-fpm. I am using a fresh install of arch linux, which has apache 2.4. With this version of apache, php needs to be loaded (as an option) with php-fpm via fcgi. So I have a ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1 rule. Maybe this is conflicting with the rest api controller? Because how will the /usuarios URL be routed to the symfony framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer.

The problem was with my webserver configuration.
I am using a fresh Arch linux installation - which uses apache 2.4.

With apache 2.4, some changes need to be done in the default parametrization of php to be able to run it with apache. In fact, I now had to configure it to use php-fpm and load in apache through fcgi.

I had thus to put the correct ProxyPass directive in the virtualhost conf in order for everything to work:

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/project/web    
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/user/project/web/app.php/$1
```

Notably the `ProxyPassMatch` directive needs to match ALL URLs, not only php files, as I am using URLS with no php ending for the API (e.g.`http://localhost:7080/usuarios`)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the out put of your command `php app/console router:debug get_usuarios:` you can see the route allowed **json|xml|html** as format but default value of your format is `NULL`.

> Defaults             _controller: MciAPIBundle:Usuarios:getUsuarios
>                              **_format: NULL**
>   Requirements    _format: json|xml|html

That means your format parameter is not an optional field. So you need to access `http://localhost:7080/usuarios.json` or `http://localhost:7080/usuarios.xml` or `http://localhost:7080/usuarios.html` to access this resource.

Now to the answer of your question:

> ***I don't get it: if it says (in the console) that it matches, why
>   doesn't it match in the browser?***

The `php app/console router:match /usuarios` is simulation of **path info match**. i.e. what it does is just find out the matched **router pattern**.

If you like to access this resource with `http://localhost:7080/usuarios`, you have to provide a **default format** option for your router. LIke:

```
get_usuarios:
    type: rest
    resource: Mci\APIBundle\Controller\UsuariosController
    defaults: { _format: json }
```

Comment: Very detailed answer and I understood already much more. I added the defaults. But I am still getting 404 (also with https://localhost:7080/usuarios.json, which in my countless attempts had tried before also, before adding defaults...). What else could be going wrong?

Comment: If everything setup accordingly, It should work. Unless your `getUsuariosAction` throwing a `NotFoundException` exception!

Comment: thank you for helping, I have no clue what's happening :( Still get 404, and neither dev.log nor prod.log show any error

Comment: could you answer some more question? 1. Are you getting 404 only for this route? 2. Which web server are you running? 3. What is the PHP version?